# Regular Expression in Codeigniter with routes

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, frameworks, routes

Can anyone suggest how I edit this routes to allow the last parameter to accept both _ and - characters.

```
$route['hotel/pages/(:any)/(\w+.html$)']  = 'hotel/page/redirect/$1/$2';
```

So in this instance the `\w+html$` would need to be modified to accept both `_` and `-` characters - can anyone suggest what I should do next, I've tried adding `_-` after the `w+` but this doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a character class

```
$route['hotel/pages/(:any)/([\w-]+\.html$)']  = 'hotel/page/redirect/$1/$2';
```

`[\w-]` is matching for one character from inside the brackets. I don't added `_` because its already included in `\w`. Additionally I escaped the dot, its a special character and would match any character.